# Not able to see any recorded video under http://myselenoid-host.example.com:4444/video/ in selenoid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, selenoid

I'm not getting any video list under http://myselenoid-host.example.com:4444/video/

But I can see video recorded inside the video folder using the terminal.

[image]

tried this as well:- http://myselenoid-host.example.com:4444/video/selenoid35dcb7f73181cb2ec321d151ed663366.mp4 but no luck :(

Comment: Selenoid is showing directory specified with `-video-output-dir` flag (default is `~/.aerokube/selenoid/video`).

Comment: Yes i have used same command to run selenoid ; docker run -d --name selenoid_v1 -p 4444:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  -v `pwd`/config/:/etc/selenoid/:ro -v `pwd`/video/:/opt/selenoid/video/ -e OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=`pwd`/video/

Comment: Yes i have used same command to run selenoid ; docker run -d --name selenoid_v1 -p 4444:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  -v `pwd`/config/:/etc/selenoid/:ro -v `pwd`/video/:/opt/selenoid/video/ -e OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=`pwd`/video/